# how to calculate clock rate(frequency) in Artificial intelligence or Deep Learning Task?

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, artificial-intelligence, cpu, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have a project about Offloading on Jetson Nano with Python

How to calculate clock rate(frequency) in In Artificial intelligence(AI) or Deep Learning Task?

classically in Computer science (offloading), executed time(or CPU Time) is Product of CPU Clock cycles and Clock Cycle Time.

1. classically Clock cycle time is inverse of frequency of CPU, but how about AI Task?
   Because I think in AI(or DL) GPU have also big role in Task,
   So should I add just each frequency?
   For example, CPU has 1.5GHz and GPU has 800MHz, then GPU has lower but in AI GPU is more powerful or?
2. and secondary for estimated execute Time, I have to calculate CPU Clock Cycles, but I don't know now, how I exactly calculate this, have someone opinion about this?

Comment: There is no difference between AI software and other programs.

Comment: Oliver Mason, thanks for your comment :D
I see, then in executed Time for KI App, GPU has a no rule?
Because noramlly, executed Time is Product of CPU Clock cycles and Clock Rate(of CPU).
Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends what you want to do; do you eg take into account that a CPU might have multiple cores?  So how do you calculate the execution time for that? Surely (in the old days when they still existed) a mathematical co-processor would not affect the excution time calculation?